# I added a new class to my project and got an error saying "Program.Main() has more than one entry". Why?

Tags: c#

The problem is that after I added the new class, the error came up when I did build the solution. What can be wrong?

In Form1, I don’t have any code yet.

I just added a new class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace OpenHardwareMonitorReport
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();

            var temps = new List<decimal>();
            foreach (var hardware in computer.Hardware)
            {
                if (hardware.HardwareType != HardwareType.CPU)
                    continue;
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType != SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        if (sensor.Value != null)
                            temps.Add((decimal)sensor.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (decimal temp in temps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I see file *Program.cs* and the error on Main():

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NvidiaTemp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

Error 2  Program 'D:\C-Sharp\NvidiaTemp\NvidiaTemp\NvidiaTemp\obj\x86\Debug\NvidiaTemp.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'NvidiaTemp.Program.Main()'. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. D:\C-Sharp\NvidiaTemp\NvidiaTemp\NvidiaTemp\Program.cs  14  21  NvidiaTemp
```

Comment: You have two `Main` now.

Comment: It may or may not be the case here, but using [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) can under certain circumstances add an implicit `main()` entry (even though this second `main()` is not anywhere in the source code) and result in this symptom. See e.g. [Jesse Q's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747761/i-added-a-new-class-to-my-project-and-got-an-error-saying-program-main-has-mo/54349868#54349868).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A C# program can only have one Program.Main(). Main is the first method run when the program starts, so the compiler needs to know which one is the real one, and it can't if you have two.

It looks like you're making a Windows application. You should either add code to the existing main, or add it to an event handler triggered by your main form.

Answer (score 90):

I experienced this issue after adding an [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) test class to my .NET Core 2.1 project.

The following article gives a detailed explanation of *why*, and provided the answer that worked for me - [here](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/).

Basically, the compiler automatically generates a `Main` for the new class. You can provide a directive in your .csproj file to keep this from happening:

`<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>`

Add this to your `<PropertyGroup>` section and recompile.

Comment: I ran into this problem with [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) (.NET Core 3.1 on Linux).

Comment: This occurred for me when I added the NuGet package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`

Comment: If you are using vscode, use `dotnet new xunit -n Tests` to create a new xunit test project. Thi will save your time by adding the right configurations in your .csproj file.

Comment: I also get the CS0017 error message. I added the <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile> to my .cs.proj file but still get the CS0017. Also, if the compiler automatically generates a Main for a new class, does that mean we don't have to explicitely write Main? I removed Main to test this out and the compiler complained until I put it back in.

Comment: So, the problem is, that at compile time it has generated two or more `exe` files?

Comment: Solved my problem with .NET 7 and xUnit

Answer (score 35):

Others have pointed out that you have two static void Main methods. There are two easy fixes for this, one obvious and one that hasn't been specifically mentioned yet:

1. Rename one to anything else e.g. `Main1`, `NotMain`, etc.
2. To set the */main* compiler option [mentioned by Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747761/i-added-a-new-class-to-my-project-and-got-an-error-saying-program-main-has-mo/11747835#11747835), just right click on the project node in Solution Explorer, select Properties, and in the Application section select the "Startup object" in the dropdown.

With solution 2, you can have identical `Main(string[] args)` signatures in different classes without the compiler whining.

Comment: finally someone pointed out how to adjust `/main` using Visual Studio (... who's seriously compiling their C# projects at the command line?)

Comment: Great answer but I found I also had to restart VS before my new class would appear under the startup object selection.

Comment: Should I select a new Startup Object in project properties each time I create a new class with its own Main method? In other words, when I create a new class in the project with a Main method, should I designate that class as the startup object to avoid the CS0017 error? I read that the compiler automatically generates a Main for a new class, which should mean we don't have to explicitely write Main. I removed Main to test this out and the compiler complained until I put it back in. I'm new to C#/VSCode 2019 so I may be missing something. I did not experience the CS0017 issue in Java/Eclipse.

Comment: @AnneBailly, you should ideally only have one Main method in your project. When you write a console application, there can be only one entry point to the executable (startup method), and that is what the `Main` method denotes. That is why, when you have more than one, you have to tell the compiler which one to use as the entry point. If you add other classes, you should use different method names, unless you intend to switch back and forth between different startup behaviors each time you compile the app (which would be a weird approach).

Comment: Solution 2 worked perfect for me, although, I didn't have a choice it was simply ``app``

Answer (score 16):

Having two *Main* methods is just fine. If you receive the error you mentioned then you need only to tell Visual Studio which one you'd like to use.

1. Right-click on your project to view the properties.
2. Go to the *Application* tab and choose the entry point you desire from the *Startup object* dropdown.

Here's an example where I have two entry points depending on how I want to dev-test the assembly.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Should I select a new Startup Object in project properties each time I create a new class with its own Main method? In other words, when I create a new class in the project with a Main method, should I designate that class as the startup object to avoid the CS0017 error? I read that the compiler automatically generates a Main for a new class, which should mean we don't have to explicitely write Main. I removed Main to test this out and the compiler complained until I put it back in. I'm new to C#/VSCode 2019 so I may be missing something. I did not experience the CS0017 issue in Java/Eclipse.

Answer (score 10):

A .NET program should have only *one* static `Main` method.

You have two, and the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

Rename the pasted one, unless you want *it* to be the entry point to the application (in which case, rename the other), or compile the application passing using the `/main` switch specifying *which* of the `Main` methods to use.

See [Main() and Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) on MSDN for more detail:

> **The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application**. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.). When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.
>
> **There can only be one entry point in a C# program.** If you have more than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as the entry point. For more information, see /main (C# Compiler Options).

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 7):

An entry point may be chosen by add `StartupObject` into your .cspoj

```
<StartupObject>MyApplication.Core.Program</StartupObject>
```

See [-main (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option)

Comment: This worked for me because I did not add an xUnit thing to my project.

Comment: This one worked for me using VS on Mac by following exactly what Maksym said.

Answer (score 6):

You have two Main methods, and that is why you are getting this error.

From [MSDN - Main Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3)

> There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have **more
> than one class that has a Main method**, you must compile your program
> with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as
> the entry point.

Answer (score 4):

When you add a new class in your project and also you write the *Main* method, and when you run your code at that time it shows the error like "More than one Main method found", then you just need to:

1. Right click on your project name which is shown in "Solution Explorer" then
2. go into *Application* and in the *Startup object* dropdown menu choose your class which you want to run. If you don't find your class name in it, then simply just *restart* your IDE and again follow the above steps.

Answer (score 4):

Did you recently add unit testing (XUnit) to your project?
Then this is the reason for you error message. You can read about the details in [this blog post](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/).

The solution is simple:
Edit your .csproj file and add a `GenerateProgramFile` property with value `false` to a general `PropertyGroup` (one that has no conditions):

Example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have fixed the error and Visual Studio still gives you error message, it's worth to remove output folders (by default "bin" and "obj") and then rebuild the project. In my case just clicking on "rebuild" did not help.

Comment: Alternatively, rename the two folders (to make an investigation of why exactly this happened possible). E.g. the contents of the new and old folders could be compared.

Answer (score 0):

My demo project had the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` Nuget package left over from some tinkering.

Removing this Nuget package resolved the error even though I had no tests or test projects in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Program 'output file name' has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

A program can only have one Main method.

To resolve this error, you can either delete all Main methods in your code, except one, or you can use the StartupObject compiler option to specify which Main method you want to use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0017

Just go to "StartupObject compiler option" and select your program as startup object.