# project file build is succeeding but source file build is failing in c#

Tags: c#

I just started learning C# and getting this error message while building the solution.

> error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile
>   with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point

I understand that "A C# program can only have one Program.Main()".

And one more thing I noticed is that, Project file build is successful but the source file(.cs) build is failing.

I mean for all the class files I add, build is failing and throwing the above error message.
I am using MS Visual Studio Express 2015.

But where am I wrong?

```
class Class1
{
    static void Main() 
    { 
        int a, b, c;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        c = a > b ? a : b;
        Console.WriteLine("greater number among {0} and {1} is {2}" ,a,b,c);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Added a new class to my project and get error say Program.Main() has more then one entry why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747761/added-a-new-class-to-my-project-and-get-error-say-program-main-has-more-then-o?noredirect=1&lq=1). When you created the solution, a `Program.cs` file was added to the project which already contains the static `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Each project can only contain a single .Main() function as this is the function called initially to run the program. Based on you question I assume that you have multiple class files which has a .Main function, which is not allowed.