# How to make two C# programs work like in Java preventing the multiple entry point errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have two programs, q1.cs and q2.cs. A class is defined inside both of them, and the main method is also there. And when I do `dotnet run,` I get the error:
**Program has more than one entry point defined**
In comparison to Java or using Intellij. I could have multiple files having the main method
and could right-click on a file and run it.
Is there something similar available for C# in `visual studio code`
or any easy alternatives. It seems weird not having this simple functionality.
Does that mean I will have to create a new project every time I want to run a simple program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: "Program has more than one entry point defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152454/visual-studio-code-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined)

Comment: @Filburt The solution mentioned there is for the visual studio, not vs-code.  Separately, I am also interested in knowing why this simple functionality is not there. I mean there should be some way to specify like `dotnet run q1.cs` and then it runs only the q1.cs file

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747761/i-added-a-new-class-to-my-project-and-got-an-error-saying-program-main-has-mo)r:

> Having two Main methods is just fine. If you receive the error you
> mentioned then you need only to tell Visual Studio which one you'd
> like to use.
>
> Right-click on your project to view the properties. Go to the
> Application tab and choose the entry point you desire from the Startup
> object dropdown. Here's an example where I have two entry points
> depending on how I want to dev-test the assembly.

[image: Application properties]

In this window select your desired class containing Main method. Using this method you can have project with more than one class containing Main method.

Doing so sets following node in project's .csproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>TrelloMonitor.Console_Looped</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In your case, TrelloMonitor.ConsoleLooped is replaced with your selected class namespace and class name.
You can edit project's .csproj file directly and set your project's entry point, this file is an XML file.

Another solution is using this command line for building project `dotnet build foo.csproj -p:StartupObject=foo.Program`, In this case `foo.Program` specifies main class or project entry point.

Comment: @Abedini I am using vs-code, so I directly inserted the `startupobject` tag with the class name I want to run  It seems to be working. Thanks a lot, But this still requires manual work if I have ten C# files, then for running any one of them, I will have to modify the value of the startupobject tag in the .csproj file; I am not sure if vscode provides some inbuilt way to do that  Also, I don't see a run button in Vscode, neither when right-clicked on a .cs file  It just shows one little relevant option like `Run tests in context`

Comment: Does the foo in the command you mentioned refer to a namespace? I get some error - `MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: Q1` whereas using the tag      
  `<startupobject>Q1</startupobject>` works

Comment: Yes foo is namespace.

Comment: My project's default namespace is C_ I haven't specified any namespace inside the class. So when I am running `dotnet build C_.Program -p:StartupObject=C_.Program` or `dotnet build Program -p:StartupObject=Program` I get the same error.  I tried using the command `dotnet msbuild` surprisingly it doesn't give the multiple entry point error and is automatically picking up an entry point.

Comment: `dotnet build C#.csproj -p:StartupObject=C_.Q1` This command succeeds. On executing `dotnet run` its running the main method inside the Program.cs instead of q1.cs, which has Q1 class defined. Probably this requires manually creating multiple .csproj files

Comment: If you got result with `dotnet build C#.csproj -p:StartupObject=C_.Q1`, I think there is no need for multiple .csproj files.

Comment: One simple way for using `dotnet build C#.csproj -p:StartupObject=C_.Q1` is running this command via multiple batch files that differ is StartupObject